# UITableViewCell's contentView custom subView is going missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was doing some memory leak profiling and noticed that the customView I am adding to my tableview cells contentView are building up and never being destroyed. I'm sure I'm handling them correctly.

I only have 5 cells in the table but occasionally when this function is called it dequeues a cell which has no subViews in its contentView.

I don't understand how this can happen? The contentView is never actually getting destroyed, just removed from the cell somehow.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

I have posted my function below.

Thanks
Stewart

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString* const CELL_IDENTIFIER = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

    BRAContentView *contentView = nil;
    for ( UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews )
    {
        if ( [subView isKindOfClass:[BRAContentView class]] )
        {
            contentView = (BRAContentView*)subView;
            break;
        }
    }


    if ( !contentView )
    {
        contentView = [BRAContentView content];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contentView];
        [contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        NSDictionary *viewDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:contentView forKey:@"contentView"];

        NSArray *constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[contentView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDict];
        constraintsArray = [constraintsArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[contentView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDict]];

        [cell.contentView addConstraints:constraintsArray];
    }

    contentView.delegate = self;
    // customise contentView here

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where you are creating the cell?? Create only when the cell is nil. If (nil == cell) {do your operation}

Comment: `contentView = [BRAContentView content];` this here, what is it returning ??? an autoreleased object or an allocated object ?? and this is iOS6 if I am not wrong ??

Comment: I am not creating the cell anywhere, this is the entire function. the app is only supporting ios6 only.

Comment: [BRAContentView content] creates an instance of BRAContentView class from a nib and returns that instance. I'm using ARC